# Why is r-squared so small when there does seem to be a dependency in my data?

Tags: regression, r-squared

What I need to do is to find a model that can predict what the **observation** should look like given a **factor** input. I am doing a simple linear fit in R (i.e., `lm(observation~0+factor, data=d)`); the $R^2= 0.002$, which is really small.  However, when I do a `SELECT AVG observation by 0.001 BRACKET factor`, the result is something like:

```
factor   | average observation
----------------------------------------
-0.003        -2
-0.002        -2
-0.001        -1
 0.000         1
 0.001         0
 0.002         1
 0.003         2
```

It definitely seems to me that there is a pattern here, but somehow this pattern is not captured by a linear model. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: What is, "when I do a `SELECT AVG observation by 0.001 BRACKET factor`"? That doesn't seem to be R code. Why are you suppressing the intercept (`observation~0...`)? You added the `[logistic]` tag; does this have anything to do w/ logistic regression? (You are using `lm()`, not `glm()` for your model fit.) What are your data? What do they stand for? How were they gathered?

Comment: (i) If you have no intercept ("`~0+`") the definition of (and meaning of) $R^2$ is different; (ii) even when you have an intercept, and the model is correct, and the mean *clearly does* change linearly with $x$, $R^2$ can still be almost zero; (iii) why does your question have the 'logistic' tag?

Comment: Can you provide a boxplot (x-axis is factor, y-axis is the value of observations)? Or can you provide a frequency table? I think you may have different counts for different categories.

Answer (score 5):

I think that your problem might be that you treat your "factor" as a factor (i.e. categorical variable), which is apparently not the case here, and not as a continuous variable.

```
> a <- read.table( text= "-0.003        -2
+ -0.002        -2
+ -0.001        -1
+  0.000         1
+  0.001         0
+  0.002         1
+  0.003         2" )

> summary( lm( V2 ~ 0 + V1, data= a ) )

Call:
lm(formula = V2 ~ 0 + V1, data = a)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.6786 -0.5000 -0.3214  0.0000  1.0000 

Coefficients:
   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
V1    678.6      112.0   6.059 0.000916 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.5926 on 6 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8595,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8361 
F-statistic: 36.71 on 1 and 6 DF,  p-value: 0.0009162
```

As you can see, my (adjusted) $R^2$ is 0.84, and not 0.002.

EDIT: I'm leaving my answer here, but please see whuber's reply below.

Comment: +1. Just to avoid confusion, the R² is .86; it's the adjusted R² that's .84 in your output.

Comment: It's unclear how relevant your example may be, because the data offered in the question are *averages.* If there is a lot of scatter around those averages, the $R^2$ can indeed be low. For instance, run this variant of your code: `k <- 20000;
a <- data.frame(x=rep(seq(-0.003,0.003,0.001), k),
                y=rep(c(-2,-2,-1,1,0,1,2), k));
set.seed(17);
a$z <- a$y + rnorm(length(a$y), sd=30);
summary(lm(z ~ 0+x, data=a)); sapply(seq(-0.003,0.003,0.001), function(i) round(mean(a$z[a$x==i]),0))`

Comment: @whuber: yes, that is a very good point.

Comment: Re your edit: I hope the O.P. (user28805) will clarify this issue by supplying some more information about the averages--especially the amount of scatter around them. Then (if you like) you could readily modify your answer to assure its relevance. (+1)

Comment: Hi, guys, thanks a lot for you all. For compliance reason, I cannot post detailed data here. But as @whuber have inferred, the std dev of each bracket is very high. Basically, the data is very noisy.

Comment: the reason that I put a logistic tag here is that, i feel the factor should not be treated as a continuous variable, but rather a sequence of catelogs.

Comment: The [tag:logistic] tag would not apply to a categorical response unless it is purely binary. If your data are indeed "very noisy," as exemplified in my code where the SD within each group is an order of magnitude greater than the SD of the mean responses, then it is probably adequate to treat them as continuous and not categorical.